# Copy/Paste functionality lost

Tags: windows-vista, keyboard-shortcuts

I've had this problem a few days. I seem to have lost Copy/Paste functionality via keyboard in Vista SP2. Anybody know what causes it? Any suggestions to recover other than reboot?

I run numerous programs together and now have a number of MS VPCs open and a couple remote sessions. As such, I don't want to just reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [article by Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/06/04/8572362.aspx). I know it talks about remote desktop/terminal services mostly, but it does briefly mention Virtual PC.